# Select posts from list and add them in a new list

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, ajax, javascript

There is this [fanduel website](https://www.fanduel.com/games/83870/contests/83870-260754332/enter) webpage with functionality to add players from left to selected players list in the right. Also when we click on filtering by position they are filtered without reloading the website. I want to do this in my wordpress website.

I created custom post type for players and I think I can select the players using checkboxes? How do I add them and appear in the correct position(C, PG, SG, PF, SF) for list box in the right side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom taxonomy for the filters in the list box (C, PG, SG, PF, SF).

If you want to make sure they are "filtered without reloading the website" you need to load all the players and the filters and manipulate them client side with JS. I usually add the taxonomy names to data-attributes and use the jQuery Attribute contains selector for this.

-Deepti Boddapati